# Wp add_action parameter error

Tags: wordpress

I have a test.php plugin file inside my plugin/ folder and I am trying to send an email from this plugin.

I have a code that looks like this currently in my plugin

```
   add_action('init', 'email_notifier', 10, 5);

   function email_notifier($type, $email, $subject, $body, $link){
    // wp_mail(....)
   }
```

However, I am not sure what is causing this error.

```
Warning: Missing argument 2 for email_notifier() in C:\....\user\templates_ajax_functions.php on line 35
Warning: Missing argument 3 for email_notifier() in C:\....\user\templates_ajax_functions.php on line 35
Warning: Missing argument 4 for email_notifier() in C:\....\user\templates_ajax_functions.php on line 35
Warning: Missing argument 5 for email_notifier() in C:\....\user\templates_ajax_functions.php on line 35
```

Answer (score 1):

Wordpress init hook have no parameter to pass and you are trying to get 5 arguments of it. As per your code, it seems that you are using wrong hook.  You can check init hook documentation on https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/init

For send mail on init you can write code like below:

```
add_action( 'init', 'my_custom_init' , 99 );
function my_custom_init() {
    wp_mail( 'mail@yourmail.com', 'subject', 'body contet of mail' );
}
```

You can see wp_mail function  documentation on https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_mail/

To change wp_mail() function's parameter, please refer below code:

```
add_filter( 'wp_mail', 'my_wp_mail_filter' );
function my_wp_mail_filter( $args ) {

    $new_wp_mail = array(
        'to'          => $args['to'],
        'subject'     => $args['subject'],
        'message'     => $args['message'],
        'headers'     => $args['headers'],
        'attachments' => $args['attachments'],
    );

    return $new_wp_mail;
}
```

To see wp_mail filter documentation, please visit https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/wp_mail

To change content type of mail, please refer below code:

```
add_filter( 'wp_mail_content_type', 'set_content_type' );
function set_content_type( $content_type ) {
    return 'text/html';
}
```

To see documentation of wp_mail_conten_type filter, please visit https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/wp_mail_content_type

Comment: So, is there any solution to this problem? Is there anything I can do about this?

Comment: Why this function you are writing? So I can suggest you proper hoo. are you looking for wp mail hook?

Comment: Yes, I can't use wp_mail in my plugin, it says undefined function. So, I need to use wp_mail to send emails, the problem is telling wp_mail to use the subject, body ...

Comment: I have changed answer. please refer it.

Comment: That is not what I am looking for. I need the mail, subject and body content to be dynamically injected into the function that is why I tried to pass them as `email_notifier($type, $email, $subject, $body, $link)` but it doesn't work

Comment: Thanks, but I still don't understand how I can send an email with your answer. +1 for your effort though

Comment: to send email please write just  wp_mail( 'mail@yourmail.com', 'subject', 'body contet of mail' );
in your plugin file. please aware that ;localhost can not send mail.

Comment: I can send already email with the code I posted but **without** the arguments

Comment: I wrote your code and called this function `my_wp_mail_filter($args)` the args contain my email, subject, content ... but nothing is sent